# How to add a framework to CMake

Tags: macos, frameworks, cmake

I have written a small helloworld program that needs the Cocoa framework. I'd like to know how to add a framework in CMake. All the information I have found is out-of-date. I have CMake 2.8.1 on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Can you just use [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) like this: `find_library(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa)`?

Then use `${COCOA_LIBRARY}` in your [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html). Possibly setting the [`CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK.html) variable to `ONLY`.

Also, refer to this article: [How to use existing OSX frameworks](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/platform_dependent_issues/HowToUseExistingOSXFrameworks).

Comment: How does this guarantee that the Cocoa framework version of the library is included as opposed to a regular unix style library?

Answer (score 15):

another solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330634/2482283

```
target_link_libraries(program "-framework Cocoa")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Macro: target_link_framework

Supports public and private frameworks

```
macro( target_link_framework TARGET NAME )
    find_library( FRAMEWORK_${NAME}
        NAMES ${NAME}
        PATHS ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT}/System/Library
        PATH_SUFFIXES Frameworks PrivateFrameworks
        CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK only
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH )
    if( ${FRAMEWORK_${NAME}} STREQUAL FRAMEWORK_${NAME}-NOTFOUND)
        message( ERROR ": Framework ${NAME} not found" )
    else()
        target_link_libraries( ${TARGET} PUBLIC "${FRAMEWORK_${NAME}}" )
        message( STATUS "Framework ${NAME} found at ${FRAMEWORK_${NAME}}" )
    endif()
endmacro( target_link_framework )
```