# How to add linker -framework on CMake file for xcodeproj

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, cmake, core-foundation

I am trying to build a project using `cmake` with `clang` compiler.

I have already got the build working using xcode, where I am importing linker dependencies from MacOS frameworks like CoreFramework, Foundation etc. When I look at the linker command Xcode is using internally, I see that it is using

```
 - framework CoreFoundation 
 - framework Foundation
```

**Question: How to I port these linker to Cmake?**

*Example:
When I am using lib libxxx.a, libyyy.a in the probject, xcode refers to those libraries as*

`-lxxx`
`-lyyy`

*the corrosponding linker commands for cmake is simply:*

> `target_linked_libraries(project xxx yyy)`

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070101/why-i-cannot-link-the-mac-framework-file-with-cmake) help?

Comment: @PaulSanders yeah. this is what I was looking for. I wish I could give you some SoF points.

Comment: No worries, it's not a competition.