# Cairo_quartz_font giving Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error

Tags: macos, cairo, quartz, meson-build, xplane

I am trying to make a mac build of [this](https://github.com/aeroc7/cairoxp). It is using the meson build system for Cairo. Whenever I `$ make -j3` I get `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` followed by this repeated for functions in the file.

```
  "_CFDataGetBytes", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_load_truetype_table in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
```

I am using an M1 mac, however, I am running all commands with `arch -x86_64` so I doubt the M1 is the issue.

A snippet of my modified `CmakeLists.txt` in the `./src` folder:

```
elseif(APPLE)
   target_link_libraries(project_libraries
        INTERFACE

            -lm
          
   )

endif()
```

I suspect I am missing something in the `target_link_libraries` however I am not sure what the issue is.
Thanks!
P.S I have also tried linking the ApplicationServices framework however it goes unused
EDIT:
here is my full errors list:

```
  "_CGBitmapContextCreate", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextRelease", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextSetAlpha", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextSetFont", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextSetFontSize", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextSetShouldAntialias", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextSetTextMatrix", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGFontCreateWithPlatformFont", referenced from:
      _cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_atsu_font_id in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGFontRelease", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_toy in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
      __cairo_quartz_font_face_destroy in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
      _cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_atsu_font_id in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGFontRetain", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_toy in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
      _cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_cgfont in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
      _cairo_quartz_font_face_create_for_atsu_font_id in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGPathApply", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGPathRelease", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGRectApplyAffineTransform", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGRectGetMaxX", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_font_face_scaled_font_create in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGRectGetMaxY", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGRectGetMinX", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGRectGetMinY", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
  "_CGRectIntegral", referenced from:
      __cairo_quartz_scaled_glyph_init in libcairo.a(cairo-quartz-font.c.o)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random guess: You need some CMake-equivalent for the following line (because you are using a static library for cairo):

> quartz_deps = dependency('appleframeworks', modules : ['CoreFoundation', 'ApplicationServices'], required: get_option('quartz'))

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/cairo/cairo/-/blob/master/meson.build#L452

Just from the name of the function, `CFDataGetBytes` sounds like it could belong to `CoreFoundation`.

Related StackOverflow answer seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/a/18330634/436275

Per the accepted answer of the question above, you can apparently also use `find_library` to "get" frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @uli 's answer. I was also missing the

```
    "-framework ApplicationServices"
    "-framework OpenGL"
```

frameworks.
Once added, I am not getting any more errors.